# Calling C# Web API with windows authentication from external

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

We have an intranet site web app. It's angularjs on the front end and asp.net web api on the backend. Because it started out as internal it uses windows authentication. Now we want to create a true mobile web app and be able to call these web api's from outside our network.

Since it's outside I'm assuming windows authentication no longer works?

Is there a way to mimic this windows authentication from the client so the api's still work or is there something else that needs to be done on the web api to make them work both internally and externally? Any direction would be great!

Comment: Have you tried using Active Directory Federation Services? Here is the link if you want to read more about it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx